# cordova push plugin server side php

Tags: java, c#, android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

**Specs**

phonegap-plugin-push 1.8.1 "PushPlugin" in a cordova application

**Issue**

I can't seem to figure out the server side JSON to send to GCM so that I can get a bigpicture notification on the phone.

Only the message and title are appearing at the moment

```
postData = "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + RegKeyIDs + "\" ], \"data\": {\"additionalData\":\"" +
                        "additionalData" + "\", \"title\":\"" + "title" + "\", \"message\": \"" + "message" + "\", \"image\": \"" +
                        "https://google.com/randomimage.jpg" + "\", \"subtitle\":\"" + "subtitle" + "\", \"tickerText\": \"" +
                        "1" + "\", \"smallIcon\": \"" +
                        "https://google.com/randomimage.jpg" + "\", \"largeIcon\": \"" +
                        "https://google.com/randomimage.jpg" + "\", \"bigpicture\": \"" +
                        "http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg" + "\"}}";
```

Is there any documentation for server side GCM handling for big picture notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to set a `style` field to `picture` and an `image` field to the location of your image `http://path_to_image`.